# display one div and hide another div using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have created one div of id="modal". In this div there is a anchor tag .Inside this tag i am getting data from database .

```
 <div id = "modal">
 <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light_<?php echo $mode_id; ?>').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade_<?php echo $mode_id; ?>').style.display='none'"><button style="border: none;color: inherit;background-color: white; font-size: 13px;"><?php echo $mode_name; ?> : <?php echo $mode_start_time; ?> - <?php echo $mode_end_time; ?>, <?php echo $mode_day_week; ?> </button></a>
 </div>
```

Now, I want that when i clicked on anchor tag in which data is coming from database. it display the another div(id= "light_") of id light_1.and first div (modal) hide.

```
<div id="light_<?php echo $mode_id; ?>" class="white_content" style = "width: 300px; height: auto;" >
<div id="fade_<?php echo $mode_id; ?>" class="black_overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: and what's your problem??
i mean do you have any specific error?

Comment: Actually, my problem is that i am unable to hide the div(id="modal").When i click on the data which i getting from database i am getting the both div.

Answer (score 1):

This answer requires JQuery.

To hide the `#fade_*` div: you can use `$(#fade_*).delay(delay).fadeOut();`, where delay is the time it takes to hide (animation).

Apply `style: display: none` to the div you want to have hidden at first.

To show the `#light_*`div: you can use :

```
$(#light_*).text('');
$(#light_*).fadeIn("slow").append(message);
```

where message is the text that will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to call to make your code readable, like this sample:

```
<div id="modal">
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show_func()"> <!--Your Codes--> </a>
</div>

<script>
     function show_func(){
          $("#modal").hide(); //hide the <div id="modal">

          $("#light_1").show(); //show1
          //or try this one
          document.getElementById("light_1").innerHTML = "Your Codes"; //show2
     }
</script>
```